# Blender, bezier curve looks

Tags: bezier-curves

In every tutorial, bezier curve looks like that in edit mode: [image]

When I try it looks like that(not arrowlike) [image]
Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to the 2D mode as shown below to change it. In your case, the curve can bend in three dimensions. That's why it looks like that and the arrows are visible when you quit ortho view and rotate using numpad.

[image]